# Access headers of incoming request in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Using Angular v13, is there a way to access the headers of the initial, incoming request to the server, which is served by it via the Angular code? E.g., I can access the query params of that request with ActivatedRoute.queryParams, is there a similar thing for the headers? I know Angular is not the server part, still the information might be passed through to make it accessible in e.g. app.component.ts.

Comment: Do you mean the header from the response returned from the server or the header from the request sent to the server? That is 2 different things.

Comment: TO the server I mean

Comment: Implement a [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/guide/http-interceptor-use-cases), and you should able to retrieve the [headers](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#headers) from `HttpRequest`. Is this something that you want?

Comment: I don't think so since it only deals with OUTGOING requests that I send with e.g. a HttpClient, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. There is no possibility to read headers from the navigation request.

I assume you want to implement authentication for your application. The most common way to do that is oauth [pkce](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) flow

Comment: Your assumption is correct, is about making basic access authentication possible. Unfortunately there is no choice since it is what the customer wants to do

Comment: @Lemao1981 do you host your api and fe on one host, or different ones?

Comment: A nginx server is hosting the angular project, sitting in a docker container, api is sitting in other docker containers. So kinda not the same host, on same VM though

Comment: the important piece here is do you have the same hostname in url when accessing FE and API? if you are using the same host for them, you could set cookies, and use cookies as a source of authorization

Comment: Yes that would be the same. But do you mean WE would set them after having received the request as is or adjusting the request accordingly? Which would need to be done by mentioned customer

Comment: I believe you can catch redirect by your api, and then redirect user to your FE with set-cookies. it seems it should work

Comment: Ok, we'll look into that. Thanks!